# Uploading and downloading files with FTP

Tags: python, beginner, ftp, python-2.x

I'm learning Python and decided to rewrite my FTP tool from Perl to Python. The program is able to up/download files, change the directory and list the files of the current directory.

Is there anything I can improve?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import sys 
import os
from ftplib import FTP
import getpass

def menue():
    print "1) Verzeichnisse auflisten"
    print "2) Verzeichnis wechseln"
    print "3) Datei hochladen"
    print "4) Datei runterladen"
    print "9) Programm beenden"
    choice = raw_input("Was wollen Sie tun? ")
    return choice

def connect(counter):
    user = raw_input("User: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    ftp = FTP('xxxxxx') 
    ftp.login(user, password)
    counter += 1
    return ftp, counter

def list_dir( ftp ):
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')

def chd_dir( ftp ):
    change_choice = raw_input("In welches Verzeichnis moechten Sie wechseln? ")
    if change_choice not in ftp.nlst():
        print "Das angegebene Verzeichnis existiert nicht!"
    else:
        ftp.cwd(change_choice)

def upl_file( ftp ):
    file_upl = raw_input("Bitte geben Sie den Dateinamen an: ")
    curr_dir = os.curdir
    if file_upl not in os.listdir(curr_dir):
        print "Die angegebene Datei existiert nicht!"
    else:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' +file_upl, open(file_upl, 'rb'))


def dwl_file( ftp ):
    file_dwl = raw_input("Bitte geben Sie den Dateinamen an: ")
    if file_dwl not in ftp.nlst():
        print "Die angegebene Datei existiert nicht!"
    else:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' +file_dwl, open(file_dwl, 'wb').write)

counter = 0
while True:
    choice = menue()
    if choice == "9":
        print "Programm wird beendet..."
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
    if counter == 0:
        ftp, counter = connect(counter)
    if choice == "1":
        list_dir(ftp)
    elif choice == "2":
        chd_dir(ftp)
    elif choice == "3":
        upl_file(ftp)
    elif choice == "4":
        dwl_file(ftp)
    else:
        print "Falsche Eingabe!"
```

Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing proper error handling.  For example, changing the directory could fail due to a permission problem.  In addition to pre-screening each commands, you need to check the status returned by the server.  In RFC 959, linked from the [`ftplib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), you'll see that status codes ≥ 400 indicate an error.  (You'll need to include an English-to-German translation table for the errors listed in Section 4.2.2 of the RFC.  Unfortunately, the errors aren't very specific as to the exact cause.)